# How to handle the Contact URi in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I.m new to Android Contact's, I wanted to return a contact id/ contact from below URi:

```
content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/encoded?directory=2147483647#{\"display_name\":\"\u202A9500249707\u202C\",\"display_name_source\":20,\"vnd.android.cursor.item\\/contact\":{\"vnd.android.cursor.item\\/phone_v2\":[{\"data1\":\"123456789\"}
]}}
```

which is start with encoded?directory=2147483647..

can any one suggestion me here!!

Answer (score 1):

In order to fetch the contact from the external storage of the phone, we have to understand about content Resolver,Cursor which you can learn on the android documentation.As you have asked in question, to handle the contact and it's related data, we can use following code.

```
  Uri contactUri = data.getData();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String phoneNo = null;
            cursor = getContentResolver()
                    .query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor.getCount() == 0) return;
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            int phoneIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            phoneNo = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);
        } finally {
            cursor.close();

        }
```

From this sample code,We can extract the necessary data using content Resolver and content provider.
But first, we have to pass content uri through intent as below to use the above code.

```
pickContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
```

Comment: The URi having append with json data in which scenarios we will get any idea??

Comment: Please make your question more clear so that I can help you?